# The network connection was lost. - Only on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, webserver, nsurlconnection

Here is my method to send a command to my server:

```
- (void)sendCommand:(NSString *)command
{
    NSURL *phpURL=[NSURL URLWithString:[DTAPI_Host stringByAppendingString:DTAPI_Path]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *phpRequest=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:phpURL];
    [phpRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [phpRequest setValue:@"Accept" forHTTPHeaderField:@"application/json"];
    [phpRequest setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", command.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];
    phpRequest.HTTPBody = [command dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:phpRequest delegate:self];
}
```

In the: `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error`

I get: `Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost."`

The most confusing part is when I send the same request with, say, Safari on my Mac, it works with no problem.

What am I missing?

Comment: yes, my apologies, I meant `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error`

Comment: Are you testing it on iOS Device or iOS Simulator?

Comment: @i4Apple Both... same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use

```
[phpRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
```

instead of the reverse.

Comment: Well that was simple. Thank you! I'm curious why there was no problem with my old web host, though.